# Array_Push AutoComplete

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I have a form that gets the "From" field for the flight:

```
<p><label ></label><input type='text' name='nereden' value='' class='auto' id = "1"></p>
```

and I have the autocomplete method:

$return_arr = array();

```
 if ($conn)
  {
    $ac_term = "%".$_GET['term']."%";
    $query = "SELECT table2.CityName, table2.CountryName, table2.AirportName FROM table2 where CityName like :term";
    $result = $conn->prepare($query);
    $result->bindValue(":term",$ac_term);
    $result->execute();

    /* Retrieve and store in array the results of the query.*/

for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
if ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
  array_push($return_arr, array('label' => $row['CityName'], 'value' =>     $row['CityCode']));
    array_push($return_arr, array('label' => $row['CityName'] + " " + $row['AirportName'], 'value' => $row['CityCode']));

}
}
```

This code works fine when I exclude + " " + $row['AirportName'] but I want this autocomplete to show something like this as a dummy example:
Athens, Athens Airport

The row name, connections are all correct. How can I do this?

Thank you

Comment: This might be stupid, but what happens if you change `" "` to `' '`?

Comment: Yes, it worked now but there is a problem. I guess the field is small for that string because in autocomplete it shows 0 for the suggestions and it works. How can i prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP, the [string concatenation operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) is `.`, not `+`.

```php
array_push($return_arr, array('label' => $row['CityName'] . " " . $row['AirportName'], 'value' => $row['CityCode']));
```